# Are there any rules regarding construction near a private strip, such as stand off distance?

Tags: faa-regulations, runways

I would like to construct a facility next to a private strip.  What are the FAA rules concerning this such as stand off or height?

Comment: the approach and takeoff chart may need to be adjusted depending on the height

Comment: @ratchetfreak do private strips have charts?

Comment: At the very least you should do any construction as a good neighbour. So no placing a 200ft tower right in the approach path...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Best is to contact your FAA regional office as the details of the procedures seem to vary a bit depending on your region, and the use of the airport.

[AC70/7460](http://www.faa.gov/airports/engineering/airspace_analysis/) gives guidance the lighting and lighting of obstructions that may affect the airspace. The first paragraph reads:

> A sponsor proposing any type of construction or alteration of a
>   structure that may affect the National Airspace System (NAS) is
>   required under the provisions of Title 14 Code of Federal Regulations
>   (14 CFR part 77) to notify the FAA by completing the Notice of
>   Proposed Construction or Alteration form (FAA Form 7460-1). The form
>   should be sent to the Obstruction Evaluation service (OES). Copies of
>   FAA Form 7460-1 may be obtained from OES, Airports District Office or
>   FAA Website at http://oeaaa.faa.gov.

More information can be found here   [here](http://www.faa.gov/airports/engineering/airspace_analysis/).

The reporting requirements are laid down in [CFR 14 part 77 §77.9](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?rgn=div5&node=14:2.0.1.2.9#14:2.0.1.2.9.2.1.3)